# É possível cancelar uma conexão JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc

Eu estou usando o seguinte codigo em uma Thread:

```
            try {
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(60);
                conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(url,usuario,senha);
            }catch(Exception e){
                mensagemErro = e.getMessage();
            }
```

E em outra Thread(da GUI) tem uma janela como botão cancelar, mas não sei como cancelar o DriverManager. **conexao** é uma variavel publica.

Comment: Não resolveria fechar a conexão?

Comment: Não sou especialista no assunto, porém recomendo a leitura dos dois links [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295920/how-can-i-abort-a-running-jdbc-transaction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295920/how-can-i-abort-a-running-jdbc-transaction) [http://blog.shinetech.com/2007/08/04/how-to-close-jdbc-resources-properly-every-time/](http://blog.shinetech.com/2007/08/04/how-to-close-jdbc-resources-properly-every-time/) Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Não, eu gostaria de destravar a Thread Imediatamente

Comment: Recomendação do [SOEn](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18897533/5524514), dê uma olhada aqui [Apache Connections Pool](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/)

Comment: Na verdade não estou usando nada na outra Thread. É apenas para verificar a conexão, mas caso o usuário queira cancelar o teste. Eu pensei que isso seria algo super simples :(

Comment: Aparentemente objetos de conexão não são [Thread-safe](http://www.devmedia.com.br/thread-safe-java-entendendo-o-conceito-e-usando-em-sua-aplicacao/28858), então compartilhá-lo pode trazer resultados inesperados na aplicação.

Answer (score 0):

Especificamente para o Driver do PostgreSQL, segundo o [changelog](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/changelog.html), pelo menos a partir da versão `9.3-1101` de 14/02/2014 você pode chamar `Thread.interrupt()` na Thread tentando fazer a conexão.

Esta é uma técnica conhecida no Java para "acordar" threads que estão aguardando em alguma operação de I/O. E é nesse momento que a exceção [`InterruptedException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html) (aquela que você precisa tratar cada vez que chamada o `Thread.sleep`) faz algum sentido.

Basicamente, o método `interrupt()` ativa uma flag na thread e a desbloqueia (caso esteja bloqueada), então ela tem a change de tratar a flag e interromper o processamento.

Segundo o link do change log, o Driver verifica o bit de interrupção e lança uma exceção. Então basta ignorá-la.